# <built-in function imshow> returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, computer-vision

I tried the below code and got the following error " returned NULL without setting an error"

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\us\\Downloads\\spurthi122.png')
l=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imshow(l,img)
```

please help me in eliminating the error. Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: NULL? Do you mean `None`? Please provide the *exact* traceback you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
img=cv2.imread('C:\Users\us\Downloads\spurthi122.png')
```

remove the `\\` slashes and replace with `\`

Comment: Thank you so much!!